# How to re-authenticate (re-call an API) in server components

Tags: next.js, next.js13, react-server-components, app-router

So I have a scenario, where I have to generate a auth token, for that purpose I am using Server Components from Nextjs 13 App Router, in the layout.js (RootLaylout) I have written the logic to fetch the token and later saves it with the help of Client Component. But the new concern arising is, once the token expires and the user is still using the app, we need to re-fetch the token to mover further in the app, But as I am using Server components, it is not simple to re-fetch the token, other than making the token call on client side (which won't work for us, as we do not want to expose the auth API to browser or client).

I have been able to find some solution but I don't think they are the right ones and kind of work through only.

1. **Server Actions**
   using server actions I can check if the token is good or expired, if expired I can use a server action to call auth api, which does make the request on client, but swaps the API endpoint, with the app url. This doesn't suits as **Server Actions** are still a experimental feature and who'd want to use any alpha features on prod.
2. Kind of hack:
   In this approach, what I have done is created a separate route for the auth say "/auth" rendering obviously Server Components to retrieve token, once I get to know that my token is expired, I open a new tab with path being set to "/auth" and fetches the token, saves it in redux, then close that tab, woo we are back on our original page with new token.

It is working but doesn't seems a good solution, Also kind of spoil of user experience and user might close the tab even before the token is fetched. There also might be a case where browser blocks this popup.

Here is a code on how the token is being fetched in Layout.jsx (RootLayout)

`Layout.jsx`

```
const getToken = async () => {
  const auth = fetch('/authenticate')
  return auth.json()
};

export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  let authData = {};
  try {
    let response = await getToken();
    authData = { response };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('widget auth error', error);
    authData = {
      response: { error: 'Some Error Occurred' }
    }
  }

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Wrappers authData={authData}>
          <main>{children}</main>
        </Wrappers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`app/auth/page.jsx`

```
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function AuthPage({ children }) {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.close();
  }, []);

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <></>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**Note: I am not making any token call in the `auth/page.jsx` as it is anyway gonna embedded to Layout.jsx**